# C++ constexpr auto member function. Clang issue?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, c++14, constexpr

```
 #include <utility>

 struct A {
     constexpr auto one(int a) {
         return std::integral_constant<int, _data[a]>{};
     }
     constexpr int  two(int a) const {
         return _data[a];
     }

     int _data[10];
 };

 int main() {
     constexpr auto ex = A{{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}};

     std::integral_constant<int, ex.two(3)> b{};
 }
```

The code above will not compile in trunk Clang.  The error is in the `one()` member function, and says:

```
cc.cpp:57:44: note: implicit use of 'this' pointer is only allowed 
  within the evaluation of a call to a 'constexpr' member function.
```

Obviously, the function is marked `constexpr`, and if you comment out the `one()` member, everything compiles fine, so we are clearly able to create the `integral_constant` from the `ex`, but not directly from the `struct`?  It seems like, when I need the `auto` return type deduction, it fails and claims the function is not `constexpr`?

Is this expected?  I feel like it should not be a problem, and I would be surprised if this was expected behavior.

Comment: `_data[a]` is not a constant expression inside `A::one`. Note that `constexpr` functions can still be called at runtime, e.g. if you supply arguments that are only known at runtime.

Comment: It is a constexpr inside of `two`, as evidenced by using its return value as a template parameter?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `_data[a]` is not a constant expression in both member functions. But constexpr functions can consist of non-constant expressions. The rules are rather: In a context that requires a constant expression, non-constant things must not be evaluated (including parts of a constexpr function). Additionally, there must be a way for a `constexpr` function to be legally called in a context where a constant expression is required.

Comment: @dyp You're missing the fact that `constexpr` is a qualifier, and the behaviour is changing depending on the call site. In that way `two` knows that `A` is `constexpr`, and do is `this->data[a]`. The interesting part is why does it think that `one` is ill-formed.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph `two` does not know that the instance has been declared as `constexpr`. Consider `A a {rand()}; a.two(0)`. This is perfectly legal yet the function-call expression `a.two(0)` cannot be a constant expression.

Comment: @dyp No, it's not legal. You don't have a `constexpr` on `A`. http://ideone.com/HMQZqR

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Note that I have used simply `a.two(0)` but you're using it in a context where a constant expression is required. As I said: In this example, `a.two(0)` is legal, but is not a constant expression itself, nor can it be evaluated within a constant expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you consider this statement in [dcl.constexpr]/7:

> A call to a `constexpr` function produces **the same result** as a call to an equivalent non-`constexpr` function **in all respects** except that a call to a `constexpr` function can appear in a constant expression.

Consider the non-`constexpr` equivalent function `A::one()`. `_data[a]` cannot be used in a constant expression (as a non-type template argument) because it would involve the evaluation of `this`, from [expr.const]:

> A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the
>   abstract machine (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>   (2.1) — `this` (5.1.1), except in a `constexpr` function or a `constexpr` constructor that is being evaluated as
>   part of e;

Since the non-`constexpr` equivalent is ill-formed, it is reasonable that the `constexpr` function give the same result.

Ont the other hand, `two()` is a well-formed member function regardless of `constexpr` and your use of `ex.two(3)` is valid as a constant expression - that's why it compiles.

Comment: Magnificent answer. Could you quote a section of Standard that tells why does `two` work in constant expressions? The part that `this` gets `constexpr`-qualified when the method is called on `constexpr` object was determined by me in experimental way.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph The Standard provides a list of things that would prevent an expression from being a constant expression - just none of them apply. [ ] `this` **except** in `constexpr`, [ ] call function other than a `constexpr` function, [ ] call undefined function, [ ] UB, [ ] lambda, [x] lvalue-to-rvalue conversion but [x] **unless** refers to a non-mutable sub-object of an object defined with `constexpr`, ...

Answer (score 2):

1. `constexpr` functions are made so that they can be called both at compile-time and run-time.
2. Code with a `constexpr` function is well-formed if you can omit `constexpr` and get a proper plain function. In other words it *must* compile as a run-time function.
3. If the body of `constexpr` function cannot be calculated at compile-time, it's still compiled, but you cannot use it in a compile-time context such as template arguments.
4. If `constexpr` method is called on `constexpr` object, `this` is considered constexpr.

In case of `one` it is ill-formed, because when it's compiled to be run at run-time, `_data[a]` is considered to be a run-time expression, because `a` is not a constant expression, even though `this` and `this->_data` are.

In case of `two` it compiles fine, because it works fine at runtime, and at compile-time `this` is `constexpr` as much as `a`, so that `this->_data[a]` is `constexpr` and everything works fine.

Comment: Removing the `one` function compiles fine, and `two` is being used in a compile time context?

Comment: It's literally in the example, I use the call to two as a template parameter.